# Lexeme position in tsvector

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I have the following lines of text:

`"Blue pill";
"Red pill";
"Blue shift";
"Red eye"`.

I want to select rows, where `Red` is the first word or where `Pill` is the second. Hypothetically, it can be done with use of `tsquery` and `tsvector`, since output of `tsvector` contains also positions of each lexeme. However I didn't find any function allowing to access vectors lexemes by their numbers.
Is there any proper way of selecting the rows, matching `ts_query` at the defined positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **possible** to do this with tsvector:

```
with data as (
  select * from (
  VALUES (1, 'Blue pill'),
         (2, 'Red pill'),
         (3, 'Blue shift'),
         (4, 'Red eye')
  ) v(id, t)
)
select id, lexeme, positions
FROM data
CROSS JOIN unnest(to_tsvector(t)) u(lexeme, positions, weights)
WHERE (lexeme = 'red' and positions @> '{1}')
OR (lexeme = 'pill' and positions @> '{2}');
 id | lexeme | positions
----+--------+-----------
  1 | pill   | {2}
  2 | pill   | {2}
  2 | red    | {1}
  4 | red    | {1}
(4 rows)
```

I think it's likely easier to do this with a regular expression, though.

Comment: Well, if it's only possible way to do it with `tsvector`, it's really much simpler to do it with regexp;